# window.blur() not working with Firefox 4

Tags: javascript, firefox, focus, firefox4

I have a function that when activated opens a new window as a pop-under under the current browser window. It was working fine with all past version of IE and FF, now it has stopped working. Apparently Mozilla has changed one of the setting of FF 4 to prevent this: http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/806756

Here is the code I am using:

```
function popup(page) {
    var myWin = window.open(page,"mywindow","menubar=1,resizable=1,status=1,toolbar=1,location=1,directories=1,scrollbars=1");
    opener = myWin.blur();
}
```

How can I get this code to work on FF 4?

Comment: "I have a function that when activated opens a new window as a pop-under under the current browser window" - you wouldn't happen to work for Netflix, would you?

Comment: lol, I was just trying to find a solution for this at work Friday. Doesn't even work if you run the code on `setTimeout()`

Comment: No, I don't work for Netflix. I run my own coupon code site. When the user clicks to copy the code it activates this function to open the retailer site in the background.

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){ window.focus(); }, 200);` doesn't work, as I thought it may have been a timing issue...

Comment: I have noticed this behavior change with Netflix ads lately in FF (was just kidding, PaperChase - I immediately think of Netflix whenever I see "popunder")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't look like you have control over this behavior...

http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/806756#answer-167267

Answer (score -1):

It seems to work if you make the popup create another child window, close it, then blur the popup window. Like so:

```
var win = window.open(...);
win.window.open('about:blank').close();
win.blur();
window.focus();
```