# Window popups - how to get window.blur() or window.focus() to work in FireFox 4?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, popup

I'm aware that FF4 doesn't allow the use of `window.blur()` unless "Raise or lower window" setting is enabled in the FF configuration. It simple ignores the event.

I'm aware that some site still manage to open a pop-up window and keep focus on your current window, even when this setting is switched off. How do they achieve this?

Additionally, I don't understand why .blur() and .focus() doesn't work when both pages reside on the same domain. According to http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/806756#answer-167267 this should work.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the site that you saw ? it might not be a pop-up in the traditional sense - might well be a div within the page that looks like a pop-up

Comment: Hi, PirateBay does it as soon as you click on any of their links.

Comment: Why support so old browser? Current Fx version is 8.

Comment: It's a requirement, not everybody updates to the newest version as soon as it comes out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me in Firefox and Chrome, in default settings ([JSFiddle](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20141004214220/http://jsfiddle.net/Gvssy/9/)):

```js
function popUnder(url, width, height) {
    var popUnderWin, nav = navigator.userAgent,
        isGecko = /rv:[2-9]/.exec(nav),
        hackString;

    hackString = nav.indexOf('Chrome') > -1 ? "scrollbar=yes" : "toolbar=0,statusbar=1,resizable=1,scrollbars=0,menubar=0,location=1,directories=0";

    popUnderWin = window.open("about:blank", "title", hackString + ",height=" + height + ",width=" + width);

    if (isGecko) {
        popUnderWin.window.open("about:blank").close();
    }

    popUnderWin.document.location.href = url;

    setTimeout(window.focus);
    window.focus();
    popUnderWin.blur();
}

document.getElementById("asd").addEventListener("click", function() {
    popUnder("http://www.google.com", 1024, 768);
}, false);
```

```html
<div id="asd">click here</div>
```

I didn't manage to get it work without the hacky extra parameters to `window.open`, so there is something to them.

Answer (score 3):

http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/806756#answer-167267

They say that it isn't possible unless everybody goes to `about:config` and sets `dom.disable_window_flip` to `false`.

I am not aware of any code that bypasses this restriction but I think the other websites use something other than `window.blur()` and `window.focus()`

There is a similar article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400086/window-blur-not-working-with-firefox-4)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. As I have said in the question, I'm aware of the restriction, but at the same time I'm aware of a number of sites that can achieve this. Their javascript is encrypted and I'm unable to have a look how they do it.

Comment: @PointedEars He said in the question The Pirate Bay. I can't visit it since my ISP has blocked it.