# Popup Window Setting Focus

Tags: javascript, function, popup, window

I have a popup window called myWindow and when it pops up i want the focus to be on the original window, not the popup.  I took out the line  `myWindow.focus();`and it still focused on the popup.  Does anyone know how to keep the focus on the original window when the popup is created?  Live Long and Prosper.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openWin()
{
myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
myWindow.focus();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Open window" onclick="openWin()" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 for "Live Long and Prosper". -1 for not binding your event handler in javascript.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996252/window-popups-how-to-get-window-blur-or-window-focus-to-work-in-firefox-4

Comment: i would appreciate just a +1 please as i am new to this...:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call `window.focus()` immediately after opening the popup, either in the function or right after it:

```
<input type="button" value="Open window" onclick="openWin(); window.focus();" />
```

or

```
function openWin()
{
myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
window.focus();
}
```

Comment: It would make more sense to include that in the function.

Comment: @sachleen - Not if he didn't want to set focus back to the main window every time he called openWin(). But I edited my answer to show both ways.

Comment: @JohnDoe - What browser are you using? I tested this code, and it's working fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: ya it worked in IE, it must just not work in MZF..thanks for the help

Comment: @jeff yeah, but that's how his attempted solution was. :p

Answer (score 4):

Call `window.focus()` instead of `myWindow.focus()`.

---

If that's not working, try blurring the window and then re-focusing it:

```
window.blur();
window.focus();
```

Comment: good idea, but that did not work.  im starting to think what i want to do isn't possible...

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. I found a workaround.

I modified like this:

```
myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
myWindow.document.write("<script>window.opener.focus();</script>");
```

It worked for me in FF and Chrome.

Comment: or re-write like this
`myWindow.document.write('<script>window.onload = function () { window.opener.focus() }</script>');`

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers it seems impossible to focus the original window.